# Mat-table-exporter CSV exporting checkbox representation of a boolean

Tags: angular7, export-to-csv, mat-table

I trying to use [mat-table-exporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-table-exporter) to export mat-table.
Does anyone have any workaround to get a a mat-checkbox representation of a boolean value to the CSV file?

Maybe [Talhature](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11420760/talhature) got any input???

Stackblitz link to a sample,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo-2toxqz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response. Saw your question, was disappointed to find no answers. I had a similar situation with icons. Took a page from the Angular Material page on accessibility and tossed in a sibling span with class "cdk-visually-hidden" that made the intended content work on export as well as be available for a screen reader.

Forked stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo-kefmjm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding this before my checkbox worked.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="hot">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hot </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">    

        <!-- added this line in -->
        <span class="cdk-visually-hidden">{{row.hot}}</span> 

        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" disabled="true [checked]="row.hot">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```